# How can I solve when navbar gives white at the top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Ruby 2, Rails 4.2 and downloaded this Bootstrap [template](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/). But when I run this template in my localhost, it shows top of the navbar white and also gives an error. When I inspect the element, the error is "undefined is not a function" inside the agency.js. Its pointing to this area.

```
// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top'
})
```

Please give a solution if anyone can. 
[image]

Comment: Check if scripts are loades in the same order as in template!

Comment: check if the jquery file is loaded using view pages source. See what is the source being generated

Comment: Love your interface :)

Comment: <script src="/assets/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

    <script src="/assets/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/contact_me.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="/assets/agency.js"></script>

Comment: It seems that element with class `navbar-fixed-top` does not exist in DOM.

Comment: How to add the element? do u have any idea. If u have please share with me.